# <Anylogic in 3 days> Airport model tutorial error

Tags: anylogic

I have been following the tutorial book "Anylogic in 3 days", in the last chapter airport model phase 6.

Setting up flights from MS excel spreadsheet, when I try to run the model after I finished all the settings, it says `The method planBoardings(Flight) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments ().`

I have checked the tutorial and my model, I don't know where I did wrong.

is there anyone who had the same problem or can you tell me where I might be wrong.

I am really new to Anylogic, I really appreciate if anyone can help!

[the model logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYxd1.png)

[startBoarding function I have defined according to the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61nTI.png)

[the Main - Agent Type property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diRDL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the tutorial itself, but your function `planBoardings` does not need an argument `flight`.

Delete that as below:
[image]

You may also need to adjust the code. Change the line below:
[image]

such that it says `create_DepartureEvent(dateToTime(f.departureTime), f)`